# Conditions in Handlebars Merge Language: how to avoid empty lines?

Tags: email-template, lightning-email-template, hml

In a Lightning e-mail template, I want to conditionally add links to photos, like this:

```
{{#if Case.Photo_1_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_1_as_link__c}}}{{/if}}
{{#if Case.Photo_2_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_2_as_link__c}}}{{/if}}
{{#if Case.Photo_3_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_3_as_link__c}}}{{/if}}
{{#if Case.Photo_4_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_4_as_link__c}}}{{/if}}
{{#if Case.Photo_5_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_5_as_link__c}}}{{/if}}
```

In itself this works. The `relevant` fields are not booleans, by the way, but formulas that are based on booleans, like this:

```
IF(Photo_1_relevant_to_manufacturer__c, '1', null)
```

However, it turns out that `{{#if}}` always generates a line in the e-mail: if a `relevant` field equals null, it generates an empty line. So depending on the values of the booleans, I get a list of links with holes (empty lines) in it. This does not look nice/professional.

Any tips on how to avoid that?

Comment: Are you sure it is the handlebars that generate the empty line? It looks like you put each on its own line (the end of line being outside the closing }}) so perhaps you need to avoid this, putting all in one line, and ensure the line endings are generated within the conditional markup itself (if possible and where needed)...

Comment: I did that because of how I interpreted Salesforce's recommendation (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.pardot_hml_conditional.htm&type=5): "For merge fields that contain links, place each link on a separate line"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phil W pointed me in the right direction (thanks!).

The solution is to use the following code:

```
{{#if Case.Photo_1_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_1_as_link__c}}}
{{/if}}{{#if Case.Photo_2_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_2_as_link__c}}}
{{/if}}{{#if Case.Photo_3_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_3_as_link__c}}}
{{/if}}{{#if Case.Photo_4_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_4_as_link__c}}}
{{/if}}{{#if Case.Photo_5_relevant__c}}{{{Case.Photo_URL_5_as_link__c}}}{{/if}}
```

Comment: Note: The final "if" tag is missing "/" 
{{/if}}

Comment: Are you sure this works in Salesforce Lightning Email Template? I am getting this error "The syntax for this field is incorrect: {{#if </code><span style="color:#2c3e50;"><span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="font-family:A...: HTML Value"